# Python fermat program only works for low numbers

Tags: python, recursion, infinite

I wrote this code in Python which is supposed to find numbers which fit the equation a^2 + b^2 = c^2.
It works with low numbers - up to about 14 - then goes haywire (infinite recursion).
I wouldn't ask if it just didn't work but I'm baffled why only works occasionally.
To use it I type eg. fermat(12,1,1)

```
def fermat(a,b,c):
    if a==1:
        print('finished')
        return
    elif b==a:
        a=a-1
        b=1
        c=1
        fermat(a,b,c)
    elif c==a:
        b=b+1
        c=1
        fermat(a,b,c)
    elif (a**2)-(b**2)==c*c:
        print(a,b,c,'fermat')
        b=b+1
        c=1
        fermat(a,b,c)
    elif (a**2)-(b**2)!=c*c:
        c=c+1
        fermat(a,b,c)
```

Comment: This is Pythagoras, not Fermat.

Comment: Note that whenever you have a list of conditionals (if, elif, elif...) in a recursive function like this, you should have an `else` statement to handle a condition where none match (even if all it does is raise an error).

Comment: If you want to compute Pythagorean triples, you would be faster by using the parametrization of Pythagorean triples, `a=(u^2-v^2), b=2*u*v, c=(u^2+v^2)` for any integer pairs `u,v`.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you have too much depth recursion. There is a limit at which the a function can call itself over and over.

I suggest you to remove the recursion with a simple loop.

Comment: Aaah! interesting, never knew that. Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

First, I rewrote your function so it's less verbose:

```
def fermat(a,b,c):
    if a==1:
        print('finished')
        return
    elif b==a:
        fermat(a-1,1,1)
    elif c==a:
        fermat(a,b+1,1)
    elif (a**2)-(b**2)==c*c:
        print(a,b,c,'fermat')
        fermat(a,b+1,1)
    elif (a**2)-(b**2)!=c*c:
        fermat(a,b,c+1)
    else:
        raise ValueError
```

Adding the `else` statement as mentioned in the comments. Your error comes from input like `(2,1,3)` which matches the condition `(a**2)-(b**2)!=c*c` and calls `(2,1,4)` then `(2,1,5)` ... This never terminates and eventually hits the maximum recursion limit.

Comment: In particular with (2,1,4/5/6/etc) calls shouldn't the c==a line above stop it calculating once c is larger than a ?

Comment: Perhaps - I'm a little unclear on what you are trying to achieve. I set out to answer your question "I wouldn't ask if it just didn't work but I'm baffled why only works occasionally.". Along the way, I tried to clean up your code and let you _exactly_ where it was failing and with what input.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way! Please be sure to upvote good answers and accept the best answer so we know this question is closed. Read the FAQ to learn the rules around here, better questions get better responses.

Answer (score 0):

The limit for recursions is probably exceeded.

Unfortunately, you would need proper tail call elimination for this approach, where the stack doesn't grow with each tail call.  [Stackless Python](http://www.stackless.com/) implementation  should help.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the answers - I never expected so much so fast. I don't 100% understand everything you said but am going to go back work on it!

Comment: IMHO it is not worth switch to a different version of python just to solve this problem. There are fundamental errors in the algorithm that can be addressed just fine in regular python.